# GIT push - Provide credentials without any prompts

Tags: bash, git

Is there anyway to provide credentials to a git push without going through the git prompt for a username and password/token?

I am converting an automated Git push script from Java to Bash and my problem is that the first 'push' command will prompt for the username and password/token. I have executed the following commands to set the credentials:

```
git config --global user.name "your username"
git config --global user.password "your password"
git config credential.helper store
```

Here is the first pass at the bash script I am trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
for tbl in $(git remote show origin); do    
  if [[ "$tbl" == *"pushes to"* ]]; then
    branchName=$(echo "$tbl" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "Pushing branch: $branchName"
    echo $(git push origin $branchName)
  fi
done
```

My version of git is 2.36 and this will be executed from within a docker container.

Do I need to create a custom git credential helper?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as outlined [in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name), `user.name` is a personal name (that is, your human name), not a username.  Similarly, `user.password` doesn't exist as a configuration option, and it's not secure to store passwords in your configuration file, so you should remove that.

If you're running this in a Docker container, the easiest thing to do is to pass the credentials in through the environment, and then read the credentials from the environment, [as mentioned in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#credential-http):

```
git config credential.helper \
    '!f() { echo username=author; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f'
```

That will set the username to `author` and the password to whatever's in `GIT_TOKEN`.

If you don't want to set that credential helper permanently for the repository, say, because the repository is shared both inside and outside the container, then you can do your push like this instead:

```
git -c credential.helper= \
    -c credential.helper='!f() { echo username=author; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f' \
    push origin $branch
```

That will first clear any existing credential helpers and then add the one from the environment.

Since you're using Docker, be sure to pass the environment variable as `ENV`, not `ARG`.  `ARG` values are built into the container, and you don't want to embed secrets into your container.

Comment: Thanks, I was having some trouble understanding the syntax of the credential helper, played around with a bit more and got it working. The !f() was throwing me for a bit of a loop. Using a Kubernetes secrets file with the ENV parm is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: The `!` introduces a shell command (that is, passed to `sh -c`), and the `f() {  };f` part is just a shell function.

Comment: Why define a function and invoke it immediately ? Can we do directly `'!{...}'` ?